# Retrieve Data and save JSON records in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I need to display the `address` in a `tableview`. How can i break the `JSON` and save the addresses in an `NSArray`.

The JSON is :

```
{
    "Rank": 54,
    "data": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "address": "x mandt "
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "address": "x mandt2 "
        }
    ]
}
```

COde is:

```
NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
NSDictionary * dat  = [dic objectForKey:@"data"];
NSArray *add =[dat objectForKey:@"address"];
```

The above code, doesn't retrieve and save all the address in the `add` array. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
NSArray *add =[dic objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Then if you want to have the address (I am considering address in 0'th index) then do this:

```
NSString *str = [[add objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey:@"address"];
```

**Edit:**

Declare a class variable like:

```
@interface YourClassName (){
    NSMutableArray *dataSource;
}
```

Populate the dataSource like:

```
dataSource =[dic objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Then In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method do this:

```
            cell.textLabel.text = [[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"];
```

I am considering you have single section in your tableview. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I want it saved in an Array, so i could populate it in a Tableview

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection` , the count always returns 0. `return [_tdataSource count]`.How can i solve this?

Comment: @Illep > Can you share where you are populating the _tdataSource??

Comment: are you sure your JSON data has been returned and parsed by the time you load your tableview? perhaps your implementation for `numberOfRowsInSection:` should be more like `return [_tdataSource count]? : 1;`

Answer (score 1):

assume that this is your serialization data

```
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

 // here I start your work 

  NSArray *infoDict=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"data"];

  for (NSDictionary *tmp in infoDict)
     {
  NSMutableDictionary *temparr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
         [temparr setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"number"] forKey:@"number"];
         [temparr setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address"];
         [_tdataSource addObject:temparr];
        }
  [yourtableviewNAme reloadData];
```

here I add the Tableview `DataSource` and `delegate` method

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
return [self.tdataSource count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"resultCell";
yourtableviewCellName *cell = [self.yourtableName dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[yourtableviewCellName alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

    }
cell.textLabel.text=[[self.tdataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"address"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: if u need any assistance i hope with U

Answer (score 1):

I think you better just use the literal syntax for retrieving this. The way you retrieve is just fine. You probably just add some introspection:

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
if (responseDict.count) {
   NSArray *dataArray  = responseDict[@"data"];
   if (dataArray.count) {
      // do whatever you want
   }
}
```

You made a mistake when you retrieve the key word *data*, you will get an array after that but not a **NSDictionary**.